# Бленд = меланж?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, іменники

Хочу нарешті розмежувати поняття "**бленд**" і "**меланж**", однак самостійно це мені, на жаль, не вдається.

У статті [Меланж у вишивці](http://lambit.com.ua/rukodillja/melanzh-u-vishivci.html) є таке пояснення цього терміну:

> ***Меланж*** поєднує в собі ніжний, плавний перехід одних колірних відтінків в інші.

У статті [Вишиванка, створена без любові, не має душі, - луцька вишивальниця](http://www.volynpost.com/articles/454-vyshyvanka-stvorena-bez-lyubovi-ne-maie-dushi-lucka-vyshyvalnycia) знайшла таке тлумачення слова "бленд":

> У картині потрібно використати 200 кольорів, також використовуються і *мішані нитки* – ***бленди***.

На скільки я зрозуміла, бленд = меланж. Однак тоді не логічно, що для одного і того ж значення використовуються 2 терміни, що не є [синонімами](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6). Принаймні на синоніми до слів "меланж" та "бленд" ніде не натрапила.

Отож чи справді бленд = меланж?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, ці поняття різняться між собою. [Меланж](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B6_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F)) – це **тканина**, зроблена з пряжі, волокна якої мають різний колір. А [бленд](http://www.volynpost.com/articles/454-vyshyvanka-stvorena-bez-lyubovi-ne-maie-dushi-lucka-vyshyvalnycia) – це [мішані **нитки**](http://vkazivka.com/sad-i-gorod/yak-pravilno-vishivati-xrestikom-dlya-pochatkivciv-pokrokovij-opis-etapiv-chitannya-sxem-a-takozh-yaki-neobxidni-materiali-foto-video.html). Також таке значення бленду знаходимо у [Як правильно вишивати хрестиком (для початківців)](http://vkazivka.com/sad-i-gorod/yak-pravilno-vishivati-xrestikom-dlya-pochatkivciv-pokrokovij-opis-etapiv-chitannya-sxem-a-takozh-yaki-neobxidni-materiali-foto-video.html).

> [...] Змішані кольори (**бленди**) на хрестики позначаються двома цифрами [...]
>   [...]Використовуйте **бленди** – змішування ниток [..]

Тобто, ці слова різняться між собою як матеріал, нитки (**бленд**) і тканина **(меланж)**.

Comment: Тобто якщо я правильно зрозумів (перепрошую, я профан у вишивці): меланж робиться спеціальними меланжевими нитками (сама нитка вже містить у собі перехід кольорів), а бленд — це коли сам вишивальник змішує різні нитки (різних кольорів). Чи я не так зрозумів?

Comment: P. S.: Було б добре зацитувати відповідні фрагменти сайтів, на які Ви посилаєтеся (бо сторінка на сторонньому сайті може перестати відкриватися (наприклад, зміна адреси) й буде тоді незрозуміло, на що саме Ви спиралися в певних твержденнях).

Comment: @Sasha, все правильно зрозуміли ( щодо двох значень)